# How can I check if a specific workbook (Excel file) is opened? After I find out, how can I close it?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I created a Python script which scrapes a website, grabs the information I need and writes it in an Excel file. The problem is that, sometimes, after I check what has been written, I forget to close the Excel file and the script no longer runs (due to the fact that the file is already opened)

To open/write/save/close the Excel file, I am using the openpyxl library, but I don't know how to check if that specific file is opened and how to close it afterwards.

```
#writing to excel
pathexcel = r'C:\Users\...\Data.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(pathexcel)
sheet = wb.active
sheet.append(row1)
sheet.append(row2)
sheet.append(row3)
wb.save(pathexcel)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use a `try` clause to save as a new file name if its opened. But I am not sure if there is a way to close a manually opened excel.

Comment: That specific file is used by another excel file (which is not on my computer) to plot graphs, and if I change its name it won't work anymore.

Comment: Well then maybe you should password lock your excel instead? Supply the password only when you need to write something to the file.

Comment: The problem is not opening it, but closing it. I sometimes forget to close it...

Comment: Then don't forget to close it.  Maybe you could use the `psutils` module to find and terminate the process that has the file opened.